# Error: Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, python-2.7

The project name is project1 and I have one app in it - home. I'm making a navbar in the index.html. However, the first `<li>` tag in the index.html gives me error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

home's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^portfolio/$', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
    url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

home's views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```

home's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/basic.css' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pranav Gupta</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      {% url 'home' as home %}
      <li {% if request.path == home %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: def index? Did you mean import?

Answer (score 3):

You dont have a url named home but you are setting it as {% url 'home' as home %}

Your root url is named index, change home to index.

Answer (score 1):

`home` is your application namespace. Your url is named `index`.

You should use `{% url 'home:index' %}`.